# How can I add rows in pandas by using "loc" and "for"?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I want to add a data of dataframe to new dataframe by "loc". I used "loc" but an error was occurred. Can I add a data?

```
>>> import pandas as pd    
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1.0, 1.2, 3.4, 4.1, 8.2]})
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A'])
>>> for i in df:
...     df_new.loc[i] = df.loc[i]
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Hajime/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1434, in _has_valid_type
    error()
  File "/Users/Hajime/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1429, in error
    (key, self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
KeyError: 'the label [A] is not in the [index]'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/Users/Hajime/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1328, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(key, axis=0)
  File "/Users/Hajime/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1551, in _getitem_axis
    self._has_valid_type(key, axis)
  File "/Users/Hajime/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1442, in _has_valid_type
    error()
  File "/Users/Hajime/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1429, in error
    (key, self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
KeyError: 'the label [A] is not in the [index]'
```

But an following code is succeed.

```
>>> df_new.loc[1] = df.loc[1]
>>> df_new
     A
1  1.2
```

Comment: This isn't a good example as you would just do: `df_new = df.copy()`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you take a look at what `for` is iterating over here?

```
In [353]: for i in df:
     ...:     print(i)
     ...:     
A
```

Conclusion - Iteration over `df` results in iteration over the *column names*. What you're looking for is something along the lines of `df.iterrows`, or iterating over `df.index`.

For example,

```
for i, r in df.iterrows():
     df_new.loc[i, :] = r

df_new

     A
0  1.0
1  1.2
2  3.4
3  4.1
4  8.2
```

Comment: Sorry, made a typo - meant "column names", not "rows". But the code snippet shows what I meant from the start.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this part:

```
for i in df:
    df_new.loc[i] = df.loc[i]
```

for **loc**, the first argument is for **index**. but **i** is a **column name**

if you just want add df to df_new. use concat.

```
df_new = pd.concat([df_new, df])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1.0, 1.2, 3.4, 4.1, 8.2]})
import pandas as pd
df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A'])
for i in df:
```

Just adding :, before i will do what you want in the first place

```
df.loc[index of row, column name]
```

Now what are you doing wrong ? You are passing column name as row index which does not exist

```
df_new.loc[:,i] = df.loc[:,i]
```

Anyhow you can pass all the columns in 1 go :

```
df_new[col_names]=df[col_names]
```

col_names is a list